# Why grep is returning non matching lines when I don't redirect stderr to stdout?

Tags: grep, stdout, stderr

The script I use is actually returning this output:

```
(source /Thetra/Commun/env_ora.sh >/dev/null; sh aclenv/arun)

geIlgif0t1 -DVORACLE
geIlgif0t1
prg_25900:
ACOMP=X
geAhadlAd1 -DVORACLE
geAhadlAd1
prg_25948:
ACOMP=A
syCcgge0t1 -DVORACLE
syCcgge0t1
prg_26023:
ACOMP=S2
syVcalq0t1 -DVORACLE
syVcalq0t1
prg_26071:
ACOMP=Y
syVvali0t1 -DVORACLE
syVvali0t1
prg_26119:
ACOMP=Y
syAedit0t1 -DVORACLE
syAedit0t1
prg_26167:
(1312) DBMS WARNING: Column not found in table. (-11238)
  RETURN (-6)
    END
 END
    END
    IF cm_para_f2('VDEF','abQtip_0n1','unicite',syAedit0t1:$v_unicite)<>0
     OR null_convert$(syAedit0t1:$v_unicite,'R') <> 'F' THEN SET syAedit0t1:$v_unicite TO 'R'
    SET $v_tips_mrgl TO 'S'
    SET $v_rfbt_iban, $v_rfbt_intitule, $v_orga_creancier, $v_orga_tip_adr1, $v_orga_tip_adr2,
        $v_orga_tip_adr3, $v_code_docu, $v_tips_centre, $v_code_etab, $v_orga_tip_emetteur,
 $v_orga_emetteur, $v_rfbt_compte, $v_orga_banque, $v_rfbt_emetteur TO
    SELECT rfbt_iban, rfbt_intitule, orga_creancier, orga_tip_adr1, orga_tip_adr2, orga_tip_adr3
ACOMP=N
syAvali0t1 -DVORACLE
syAvali0t1
prg_26215:
(2751) DBMS WARNING: Column not found in table. (-11238)
 + to_string_using$(str_to_val$(substr$(clip_str$(to_string$($f_imme_no)),1,4)),'&&&&')
        + to_string_using$(str_to_val$(substr$(clip_str$(to_string$($f_sepa_propriete_no)),1,5)),'&&&&&')
    IF syAvali0t1:$v_unicite ='R' THEN
 SET $v_sepa_rum3 TO $v_sepa_rum3 + substr$(to_string_using$(syAvali0t1:$v_ordr_direct,'&&&&&&&&&'),7,9)
    ELSE
ACOMP=N
syAcalc0t1 -DVORACLE
syAcalc0t1
prg_26263:
ACOMP=N
syAcalc0t2 -DVORACLE
syAcalc0t2
prg_26311:
ACOMP=N
syAcalc0t3 -DVORACLE
syAcalc0t3
prg_26359:
ACOMP=N
```

To check for errors I use the following command:

```
(source env_ora.sh >/dev/null; sh aclenv/arun) | egrep '^ACOMP=$'
```

Output:

```
(1312) DBMS WARNING: Column not found in table. (-11238)
  RETURN (-6)
    END
 END
    END
    IF cm_para_f2('VDEF','abQtip_0n1','unicite',syAedit0t1:$v_unicite)<>0
     OR null_convert$(syAedit0t1:$v_unicite,'R') <> 'F' THEN SET syAedit0t1:$v_unicite TO 'R'
    SET $v_tips_mrgl TO 'S'
    SET $v_rfbt_iban, $v_rfbt_intitule, $v_orga_creancier, $v_orga_tip_adr1, $v_orga_tip_adr2,
        $v_orga_tip_adr3, $v_code_docu, $v_tips_centre, $v_code_etab, $v_orga_tip_emetteur,
 $v_orga_emetteur, $v_rfbt_compte, $v_orga_banque, $v_rfbt_emetteur TO
    SELECT rfbt_iban, rfbt_intitule, orga_creancier, orga_tip_adr1, orga_tip_adr2, orga_tip_adr3
(2751) DBMS WARNING: Column not found in table. (-11238)
 + to_string_using$(str_to_val$(substr$(clip_str$(to_string$($f_imme_no)),1,4)),'&&&&')
        + to_string_using$(str_to_val$(substr$(clip_str$(to_string$($f_sepa_propriete_no)),1,5)),'&&&&&')
    IF syAvali0t1:$v_unicite ='R' THEN
 SET $v_sepa_rum3 TO $v_sepa_rum3 + substr$(to_string_using$(syAvali0t1:$v_ordr_direct,'&&&&&&&&&'),7,9)
    ELSE
```

We can see that grep is returning non matching lines.

When I redirect the stderr to stdout with this command:

```
(source /Thetra/Commun/env_ora.sh >/dev/null; sh /Thetra/Oracle/transfert/P2016.H.1/aclenv/arun) 2>&1 | egrep '^ACOMP=$'
```

As expected, the output is void.

Why grep is returning non matching lines when stderr is not redirected ?

Comment: It's not, the error output from your script goes past the pipe to your terminal. That is, a regular pipe like `aa | bee` doesn't touch the stderr output of `aa`.

Comment: @ctx, it's not **grep** that ignores anything, it reads all it gets from its stdin.

Comment: Yes that is true.

Comment: You're saying: _why is grep not filtering stderr when I don't send stderr to it?_. Do you really need an answer to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this command you'll get two files, one called `stdout` and one called `stderr`, containing the output to *stdout* and the output to *stderr*, respectively:

```
(source env_ora.sh >/dev/null; sh aclenv/arun) >stdout 2>stderr
```

Your `grep` command only sees data that is sent to *stdout*. It does not even see the data that here is written to *stderr*.

Taking a variation of your example in a follow-on comment, you'll see that only *stdout* comes through the pipe to be processed by `sed`:

```
( echo "stdout"; echo "stderr" >&2 ) | sed 's/std/STD/'
stderr
STDout
```

The other line of output is written directly to the *stderr* channel, which by default is attached to your terminal.

In summary: a pipeline attaches *stdout* from one command to *stdin* of the next. The *stderr* channel is attached to your terminal so that error messages (or status updates) can be written there without impacting the flow of actual data.

Comment: Thanks ! This is more usefull than "Do you really need an answer to that?".